# CSS Hover and Link

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a hover link using css but it's not working. Is this the correct way to create css hover links? Thanks,

I have read though this but no luck: http://w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Here is the code I have:

**CSS**

```
.Footerbullets{
padding:3px 0 3px 25px;
background-image:url(../images/menubar/footer_bullet.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.Footerbullets a.link {
color:#FFF;
}
.Footerbullets a.hover {
 color:#FF0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer"><div class="content">
       <ul>
          <li class="Footerbullets"><a href="#">Link with Hover Color Change</a></li>
       </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `div#footer ul li.Footerbullets  a:hover` instead of `.Footerbullets a:hover`, it seems that `div#footer ul li a:hover` is overriding other styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/GFec3/14/

Comment: That did it thank you! What is the difference between . and #?

Comment: `div#footer ul li a:hover` is more specific then `.Footerbullets a:hover`, that's why you should avoid that kind of css.
# is for ID's, while . is for classes, ID > classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.Footerbullets a:hover {
 color:#FF0 !important;
}
```

**My code**

```
<style>
.Footerbullets{
padding:3px 0 3px 25px;
background-image:url(../images/menubar/footer_bullet.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.Footerbullets a.link {
color:#FFF;
}
.Footerbullets a:hover {
 color:#FF0;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer"><div class="content">
       <ul>
          <li class="Footerbullets"><a href="#">Link with Hover Color Change</a></li>
       </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Nope... I tried `.Footerbullets a:hover {
 color:#FF0;
}` and this to `.Footerbullets a:link {
 color:#FFF;
}`

Comment: I have test and this is work for me.I have upload my code check it

Comment: I did and it doesn't work!! Look at my jsfiddle to see for yourself. http://jsfiddle.net/GFec3/13/  There you can see the whole css file maybe something else is wrong causing the problem.

Comment: I have check you css code in jsfiddle and solved your problem see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsfiddle with a working example for each anchor pseudo-class. I tested it and it works in the latest version of Safari at least. You can find it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kylewlacy/DqePq/

You can read about each pseudo-class and what they do [here](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/), as well